# but instead; coordinating conjunctions

Tags: punctuation, writing

Do I need to place a comma before -but- in this sentence? I suppose not, because there is no independent clause after **but**. Or am I wrong? And which option is, stylistically, preferable?

> According to the Explanatory Memorandum, the Act equips disputing parties with an auxiliary tool to refrain them from commencing legal proceedings on the merits of the case ***but instead*** helps them to negotiate an out-of-court settlement.
>
> According to the Explanatory Memorandum, the Act equips disputing parties with an auxiliary tool to refrain them from commencing legal proceedings on the merits of the case ***but*** helps them to negotiate an out-of-court settlement ***instead***.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. No comma is required in either example. The second example, which I assume you have re-written, is stylistically superior to my native ear, but that is obviously just my opinion.